# Assigning event handlers after the events may have already been emitted

Tags: node.js, events, stream

Is this wrong?

```
var f = fs.createWriteStream('file');
otherStream.pipe(f);
f.on('finish', function() { /*...*/ })
```

Should it not be this:

```
var f = fs.createWriteStream('file');
f.on('finish', function() { /*...*/ })
otherStream.pipe(f);
```

?

Which one is better, and why?

Comment: it doesn't practically matter since .pipe is async. They'll differ by one CPU cycle by which the operation would not have finished but yes, it would be symantically correct to assign it first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614161/node-js-attaching-event-handlers-on-time