# node http-proxy least connections proxy

Tags: node.js

I'd like to use node http-proxy to create a "least connections" proxy.  In other words it picks a backend that currently has the least connections.  The proxy has an "end" event, but it doesn't pass you any information, so I'm not sure how I can increment/decrement a counter for each of my backends with the current number of concurrent requests.

Comment: Pretty sure there's nothing out there that can do it -- you'll probably have to build it yourself using websockets. Alternatively, have you looked at [satellite](https://npmjs.org/package/satellite)?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to satellite. Ultimately, I'm also going to have this manage processes on the local host (could be java, node, etc ... ) and have some other features around recycling them, etc ... so the satellite code will be good to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can wait for the response to have been send to the client.

For example:

```
var backends = [
  { host : 'backend1', port: 80, active : 0 },
  { host : 'backend2', port: 80, active : 0 },
  { host : 'backend3', port: 80, active : 0 },
  { host : 'backend4', port: 80, active : 0 },
];

httpProxy.createServer(function (req, res, proxy) {
  var buffer = httpProxy.buffer(req);

  // Pick the backend with the least active requests (naive implementation).
  var backend = backends.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.active - b.active;
  })[0];

  // Add a new active request.
  backend.active++;

  // Proxy the request.
  proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
    host    : backend.host,
    port    : backend.port,
    buffer  : buffer
  });

  // When the response is finished, decrease the count.
  res.on('finish', function() {
    backend.active--;
  });
}).listen(8000);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll probably setup the res.on('finish') before I proxy.proxyRequest() just in case the res finishes before I get to setting up the callback.

Comment: @Dave that's not strictly necessary ([this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11614706/893780) explains why) :)

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense to me now!